# "System Memory" taking up too much storage

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, storage, insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I have been facing this problem recently, my Samsung S 10+ has the storage information as shown in the image below. I don't know why the system memory is taking up 20 GB of storage. I cannot access it as well. On clicking it nothing happens. Would really appreciate help.[image]